# Topological Quotient vs Group Quotient

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, category-theory, quotient-spaces

I was wondering about if topological quotients and group quotients always agree for a topological group.  By this, I mean if G is a topological group, G/~ is a topological quotient space, G/N is a group quotient where N is a normal subgroup, and the equivalence classes generated by ~ are the same as the cosets generated by N, then will G/~ and G/N be isomorphic?  One example is where ~ is defined as a~b if a and b differ by an integer.  Then R/~ sometimes shorthand written as R/Z as a quotient topology is the circle S.  Also, Z is a normal subgroup of R so one can take R/Z as a group quotient which is the circle group S.  In both cases we can write R/Z=S, but the meanings are quite different depending on if this is a topological quotient or group quotient.  I was wondering if this is a property in general or possibly a special case of using “nice” sets like R and Z.

I was also wondering if this might be a case of a more general property.  The topological quotient can be informally thought of as gluing 0 and 1 and making sure an open set can go into 0 and come out at 1 while the group quotient can be informally thought of as making sure an addition of an element can go into 0 and come out at 1.  In both cases the quotient seems to glue the points 0 and 1 and also glue the structure there whether a topological structure or group structure.  This seems to be formalized in category theory by the idea of a quotient category, but I was wondering if in general quotients for different types of categories will agree like the do for R/Z=S.

Comment: As sets, $G/\sim$ and $G/N$ are literally the same.

Comment: What do you *mean* when you ask if the topological space $G/\sim$ and the group $G/N$ are isomorphic? This doesn't really make sense. There's a lot going on here - one important fact is that the "coset relation" for a normal subgroup $N$ is always a "congruence relation", and the class of the identity in any congruence relation is always a normal subgroup. The quotient by this relation is a set and naturally has an induced group structure and an induced topological structure. These structures are compatible, which is a nice theorem!

Comment: It doesn't have much to do with quotient categories but rather with "quotient objects in categories". This becomes quite involved. There is some discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/60241). If you're not very familiar with category theory this will take some work to get to grips with.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen This seems to be answered in the answer below.  By isomorphic I meant they have the same structure, but it seems that you can’t talk about groups being isomorphic in a topological sense i.e homeomorphic until you define a topology.  After this, I believe, the topological quotient and group quotient endowed with the topology will be homeomorphic by definition.  The fact that they are compatible is more interesting and in this case may be a better phrase than isomorphic.  I am wondering if other types of quotients will also be compatible.  This is a reply to the first comment.

Comment: By wondering if they are compatible I mean will other types of quotients monoid quotients, ring quotients, etc with the same underlying quotient set also have compatibility theorems  like the one for topologies and groups.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a topological group, $N\subset G$ a normal subgroup. One has an abstract group $G/N$ of course, and one can apply the quotient topology to it. The thing to check is that $G/N$ endowed with this topology becomes a topological group. It is it turns out!

See theorem 4.15 in

https://www.lakeheadu.ca/sites/default/files/uploads/77/images/Spivak%20Dylan.pdf

Comment: That makes sense.  It seems like the quotient group won’t have a topological structure until you define it and vise versa.  I am also wondering in terms of category theory if the two notions being compatible holds for other types of quotients.